# What is a good way to manage who's coming to a monthly event?

Tags: calendar

A group of friend organizes an event about every month, but it's a hassle to nag everyone every time to find out who's going.

So what I need is a place where I can enter all events for this year, and have it send everyone a reminder, allowing them to fill in if they're coming.

I tried a few obvious solutions, like Google Calendar, but I have not found anything that automatically sends a reminder, and shows a list of who is coming.

[edit]
Not al my friends are using Facebook/Gmail/...

Concrete requirements:

1. Automatic reminders
2. List of people who are coming.

Comment: Do you want a web application, or are desktop programs also fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Calendar can send reminders to guests, if they have a Google Calendar account and they choose to add a reminder.

Otherwise, specialized event management apps include:

- Meetup.com: sends reminders
- *Smart Events (free for less than 5 attendees)*
- EventBrite (free): sends reminders
- Eventzilla (free): sends reminders
- TicketLeap (free): sends reminders
- Epic Event (free if the event is free): sends reminders
- Eventful (free): sends reminders
- DoAttend (freemium): sends reminders
- *Ticket Tailor (freemium)*
- *Amiando*
- *TicketForEvent (freemium)*
- *BookWhen (free)*
- *Guestlist (freemium)*
- MyGuestlist: sends reminders
- SimpleTix: sends reminders
- *Stage (freemium)*
- *TicketPeak*
- *EventArc (freemium)*
- EventStorm (freemium): sends reminders
- *TicketDerby*
- RegOnline (free): sends reminders
- Ticketbud: sends reminders
- CharityHappenings Ticketing (free): sends reminders
- EventElephant (freemium): sends reminders

Most specialized event management apps can send automatic reminders to users.

I've indicated the ones that *I know* can send them, either from experience or because it's stated on their site on in reviews. *Italicized entries* mean I don't know/couldn't confirm that reminders are sent.

But you can usually find out by googling `*service name* reminders` or `*service name* notifications`, visiting their site, or contacting their sales/support.

Other options include Yahoo! Events, Live Events, Facebook, and Myspace.

Comment: I personally use Facebook, but it only works for friends. Though that is what you are looking for. +1

Comment: I asked on SU, because I don't feel like signing up for 20 services to see if they fit my needs ;) (Best would be if attendants do not need to sign up for the service as well)

Comment: @Pepijn: I've only used a few of these, but I know most probably support reminder emails (some of them support SMS reminders as well). I've made this answer a community wiki so that others with direct experience can fill in the blanks.